# Chainlink Functions return an array or list of strings from Functions-request-source.js

Tags: chainlink, string, bytes, function

Hope someone can help.
I am stuck trying to work out how best to extract the different string values from the returned bytes data.
Chainlink Function request source requires the return value to be a buffer so I am including all the values required as per an example I found below from https://www.usechainlinkfunctions.com/ :

```
// Encode and return the distance (in meters), standard duration (in seconds), and duration in traffic (in seconds) as a string which can be parsed and split
return Functions.encodeString(`${distance},${stdDuration},${duration_in_traffic}`)
```

I am stuck trying to split the return values in the fulfillRequest function in the FunctionsConsumer contract. Below is the standard function before implementing anything to split out a number of string variables from the response:

```
function fulfillRequest(
    bytes32 requestId,
    bytes memory response,
    bytes memory err
) internal override {
    latestResponse = response;
    latestError = err;
    emit OCRResponse(requestId, response, err);
}
```

Here is the github repo link for chainlink functions:
https://github.com/smartcontractkit/functions-hardhat-starter-kit/tree/main#functions-library

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you're returning a string, parsing that string and splitting it would be very expensive.  Instead you could return with a buffer.concat to concat your distance, std duration and duration in traffice as uint256 values (assuming they can ONLY be positive integers) and int256 if they can be negative.

[Chainlink Functions code with Buffer.Concat example](https://github.com/smartcontractkit/functions-twilio-spotify/blob/main/Twilio-Spotify-Functions-Source-Example.js#L43)

Then in your Functions Consumer Smart Contract you use abi.decode with the exact int types. [See this code example from the same repo](https://github.com/smartcontractkit/functions-twilio-spotify/blob/main/contracts/sample-apps/RecordLabel.sol#L115)

This way you get individual values and dont have to split them on chain.

Hope this helps!